# Javascript Array Manipulation - Is there a more declarative approach?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Thanks for taking a look here. I'm working with an API, and need to change the format of the data. Here's an example of the return data:

```
data: [
  { 
    status: "planned work",
    name: "123"
  },
  {
    status: "all good",
    name: "nqr"
  }
];
```

Each train line has a name like "123" or "nqr", and I want to split each train into their own objects so that it would look something like this:

```
data: [
  { 
    status: "planned work",
    name: "1"
  },
  { 
    status: "planned work",
    name: "2"
  },
  { 
    status: "planned work",
    name: "3"
  },
  {
    status: "all good",
    name: "n"
  },
  {
    status: "all good",
    name: "q"
  },
  {
    status: "all good",
    name: "r"
  }
];
```

I have some working code which splits the name and uses nested `.forEach` loops to push items to an array. Working code:

```
function formatLinesData(lines) {
  var trains = [];
  lines.forEach( line => {
    line.name.split("").forEach(train => {
      trains.push({name: train, status: line.status});
    });
  });
  return trains;
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without the nested loops? Looking for an elegant solution if you have one.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do as follows;

```js
var data =  [
  { 
    status: "planned work",
    name: "123"
  },
  {
    status: "all good",
    name: "nqr"
  }
],

newData = [].concat(...data.map(o => o.name.split("").map(c => ({status: o.status, name: c}))));
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use reduce - initialize it with an empty array, and iterate over the data
array using your logic.

```
data.reduce((prev,curr) => {
    for (let i=0; i<curr.name.length; i++) {
        prev.push({ name : curr.name[i], status : curr.status});
    }
    return prev;
},[]);
```